# How to invoke/call performClick of menuitem of an MDI parent from another form?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a problem, sorry for this newbie question (just a 2 week visual c++ programming experience). I am currently working with MDI in Visual C++2010, here is how the program works, once you execute the application, the MDIParent loads in maximize state, then the MDIParent has MenuStrip and one of its subMenu is named noviceToolStripMenuItem. If noviceToolStripMenuItem is clicked using the mouse button, it will open a child form called frmNovice, this works out fine, now the frmNovice contains a simple game which works out according to its intended function, once the game is over a new form named frmRetry will be shown but this time frmRetry is not a childform and the frmNovice will close. frmRetry has two buttons, Yes and No, if the user clicks the No the frmRetry will close and the MDIParent will then again holds the focus of the application, but if the user clicks the Yes button, the application should perform the click event/function of noviceToolStripMenuItem, to show up again the frmNovice, but this is the problem, i can't get this done. frmRetry (not a child form) to invoke or call the click event noviceToolStripMenuItem of the MDIParent. Is there any way to do this, or maybe other solution? thanks in advance.

This are the codes (some are deleted to minimize space):

```
**FILE: mdiMain.h**

    #pragma once
    #include "frmNovice.h"
    namespace MemoryGame {
        using namespace System;
        using namespace System::ComponentModel;
        using namespace System::Collections;
        using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
        using namespace System::Data;
        using namespace System::Drawing;

        public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form {
        public:
        Form1(void)
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        }

        protected:
        ~Form1()
        {
        if (components)
         {
            delete components;
         }
        }
        private: System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip^  menuStrip1;
        protected: 
        private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  noviceToolStripMenuItem;

       private:
       System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

    #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
        this->menuStrip1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip());
        this->selectLevelToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew    
            System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
        this->noviceToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew 
        this->selectLevelToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"selectLevelToolStripMenuItem";
        this->selectLevelToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(70, 20);
        this->selectLevelToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"New &Game";
        // 
        // noviceToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        }
    #pragma endregion
    private: System::Void noviceToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sen....) {  
        //OPENING NEW FORM AS MDI CHILD
        frmNovice^ newMDIChild = gcnew frmNovice();
        // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
        newMDIChild->MdiParent = this;
        // Display the new form.
        newMDIChild->Show();
          }
    };
    }
```

**FILE: mdiMain.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mdiMain.h"
using namespace MemoryGame;
[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
    return 0;
}


**FILE: frmNovice.h**

#pragma once
#include "frmRetry.h"
#include "algorithm"

namespace MemoryGame {
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    public ref class frmNovice : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
    frmNovice(void)
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    //TODO: Add the constructor code here

    }
    protected:
    ~frmNovice()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
          //codes for the UI of the game goes here.....
#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
     //MY USER DEFINED FUNCTION START
    void gamefunction() //this function is where calls the frmRetry to show
        {
    frmRetry^ form = gcnew frmRetry();
    form->Show(); //This time not a CHILD FORM
    this->Close();
    }

void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        //initialize UI components GOES HERE
     }
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    //DIFFERENT PROCEDURE FUNCTIONS GOES HERE Also invokes/calls the game function that     
        //show the frmRetry (this is working properly)
};
}
```

**FILE: frmNovice.cpp**

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "frmNovice.h"
//there are variables used for gameplay
int Choice1; 
 int Choice2;
 int Mistakes;
 int TimeRecord;
 int AllItems;
```

and LASTLY
**FILE: frmRetry.h**

```
#pragma once
namespace MemoryGame {
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    public ref class frmRetry : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    `enter code here`public:
    frmRetry(void)
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected:
    ~frmRetry()
    {
    if (components)
    {
        delete components;
        }
    }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnYes;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnNo;
    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox1;

    private:
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
    CODES for UI inialization goes here
    }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void btnNo_Click(System::Object^  .....e) {
     this->Close();
    }
private: System::Void btnYes_Click(System::Object.....^  e) {
    **THIS IS THE PART IM STuck WITH, i CANT GET THIS DONE**
        **EVErything is working fine, except for this part where i have to                      
        call again the frmNovice as an child form of the mdiParent**
         THE following are my attempts but didnt work.
           // frmRetry^ form = gcnew frmRetry();
           // frmNovice^ frmNovice=gcnew frmNovice();
       // noviceToolStripMenuItem->PerformClick();
       //frmNovice->Show();  
     }
};
}
```

**FILE: frmRetry.cpp**

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "frmRetry.h"
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Use ShowDialog() instead.

Comment: i did dat already, but it works the same with Show() and they have the same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You should pass in a reference to the main window when you create the Novice form, and pass this reference again to the Retry form. Then, have the main window implement a NoviceParent interface, which includes a public method for the Retry form to call. The noviceToolstripMenuItem_Click method on the main window will also delegate to this new public method.

### Novice Parent Interface

```
public interface class INoviceParent
{
 public:
      void ShowNovice();
}
```

### Main Window

```
#include "INoviceParent.h"

public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form, INoviceParent {
 public:
   // ... existing public methods
     void ShowNovice() {
        //OPENING NEW FORM AS MDI CHILD
        frmNovice^ newMDIChild = gcnew frmNovice(this);
        // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
        newMDIChild->MdiParent = this;
        // Display the new form.
        newMDIChild->Show();
      }

 private:
     void noviceTooltipMenuItem_Click( /* args */) {
         ShowNovice();
     }
 // ...
};
```

### Novice Form

```
#include "INoviceParent.h"

public ref class frmNovice : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    frmNovice(INoviceParent ^ const parent)
    {
         this->parent = parent;
         // ...
    }

// ...

private:
    void gamefunction() //this function is where calls the frmRetry to show
    {
         frmRetry^ form = gcnew frmRetry(parent);
         form->Show(); //This time not a CHILD FORM
         this->Close();
    }
    INoviceParent ^parent;
}
```

### Retry Form

```
#include "INoviceParent.h"

public ref class frmRetry : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    frmRetry(INoviceParent ^ const noviceParent)
    {
        this->noviceParent = noviceParent;
        // ...
    }

    // ...
private: System::Void btnYes_Click(System::Object.....^  e) {
   noviceParent->ShowNovice();  
 }

 INoviceParent ^noviceParent;
};
```

The important thing here is that the sub-forms don't need to be strongly coupled to the main form or to each other. All they know is that the object passed in their constructor has a public method called `ShowNovice()`. The Retry form calls it when the user clicks the "Yes" button, and the main window does whatever it does when the user clicks its `noviceTooltipMenuItem`.

Comment: Shall I create the INoviceParent.h as a New Header File? having this code:   public interface class INoviceParent
{
 public:
      void ShowNoviceForm();
}

Comment: Yes, that is my suggestion.

Comment: I still cant get this done, im having errors with #include thing

Comment: You should either edit your question to show the new errors, or ask about them in a new question.

Comment: //This is the part that gets error- The error goes like:
  //Error 11 error C2664: 'MemoryGame::frmNovice::frmNovice(INoviceParent ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'MemoryGame::Form1 ^const ' to 'INoviceParent ^' c:\users\zherwyndbest\desktop\memorygamec++\memorygametpl\memorygame\memorygame\mdiMain.h 27 1 MemoryGame
  // And this: Error 2 error C2039: 'ShowNovice' : is not a member of 'INoviceParent' c:\users\zherwyndbest\desktop\memorygamec++\memorygametpl\memorygame\memorygame\frmRetry.h 142 1 MemoryGame

Comment: I made a mistake. I named the method `ShowNoviceForm` in the `INoviceParent` definition, then called it as `ShowNovice` for the rest of the code. I will edit my answer.